# Inves Wibook 660lt stuck on boot after update

Tags: boot, ota-update

My boss recently went to spain and bought himself an e-reader running Android, the wibook 660lt. He did an OTA update of the OS, but now it's stuck at the screen with a triangle with an "!" in it, with the android logo right beside it. If I press the small reset button for a few seconds, the device reboots, showing the bootscreen, after that the update starts and fails again, going back to step 1.

I've tried recovery, but I can't do it. This device does not have volume buttons, only home and a power button. If anyone knows something, that would be great C:

Answer (score 0):

Bajate el firmware de la página Inves. Lo ejecutas en tu ordenador. Bajate el RKBachtool. Pinchas el wibook, instalas los drivers y sigue las instrucciones de actualización

Translation from Spanish to English (credits @Karel):

Download firmware from the Inves page. Run it on your computer. Download the RKBachtool. Tap the Wibook, install the drivers, and follow the upgrade instructions

Comment: Translation: *Download firmware from the Inves page. Run it on your computer. Download the RKBachtool. Tap the Wibook, install the drivers, and follow the upgrade instructions.*